# Spirograph: could you break down this equation?

Tags: geometry, curves

Could you explain how the equation

$\hat{t}=-\frac{R-r}{r}t.$

can be derived from

$tR=(t-\hat{t})r$

step by step?

I'm trying to understand the mathematical aspect of Spirograph, and I found a quite nice explanation on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph), but only this part doesn't make sense to me.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Hint: first step is $tR=tr-\hat t r\,$. Then rearrange, collect and simplify.

Comment: yep, I took the first step wrongly, that's where all the confusion comes from. Thanks again! solved!